# Edit link category

Tags: php, mysql, menu, categories

### Dumping data for table `categoria`

INSERT INTO `categoria` (`idcateg`, `descri`) VALUES
(1, 'Action'),
(2, 'Classic'),
(3, 'Fight'),
(4, 'Others'),
(5, 'Puzzles'),
(6, 'Racing'),
(7, 'Shooting'),
(8, 'Sports'),
(9, 'Tower Defense'),
(10, 'Zombie');

```
$varCategorias_GameData = "0";
if (isset($_GET["cat"])) {
$varCategorias_GameData = $_GET["cat"];
}
mysql_select_db($database_gameconnection, $gameconnection);
$query_GameData = sprintf("SELECT * FROM jogos WHERE jogos.intCategoria = %s", GetSQLValueString($varCategorias_GameData, "int"));
$GameData = mysql_query($query_GameData, $gameconnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_GameData = mysql_fetch_assoc($GameData);
$totalRows_GameData = mysql_num_rows($GameData);

<a href="link_categoria.php?cat=1">Action</a>
<a href="link_categoria.php?cat=2">Classic</a>
<a href="link_categoria.php?cat=3">Fight</a>
<a href="link_categoria.php?cat=4">Others</a>
...
```

I want to edit each link related to the catedory list, wich is in my database, where is the code of the links? how can I edit each one?

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<a href="link_categoria.php?     cat='.$row['idcateg'].'">'.$row['descri'].'</a>';
 }
```